# Can't set React state with defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make the user profile editable in my component. Right now, when the user clicks "edit," the profile is replaced with a form that has the values they typed in as defaults. However, if they update only one field, the others get rewritten with blank values instead of passing the default value to the state.

Is there a way to pass the defaultValue to the state? I've tried value={} too but then the value doesn't change at all.

I'm trying to avoid having an "Edit" button for each input.

```
class AccountEditor extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isEditing: false,
      profile: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        city: '',
        email: '',
        bio: '',
      }
    }
  }

  toggleEdit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
    })
  }

  updateProfile(event) {
    let updatedProfile = Object.assign({}, this.state.profile)
    updatedProfile[event.target.id] = event.target.value

    this.setState({
      profile: updatedProfile
    }
  }

  submitUpdate(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.onUpdate(this.state.profile)
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
    })
  }

  render() {
    let profile = this.props.profile
    let content = null

    if (this.state.isEditing == true) {
      content = (
        <div>
          <input
            id="firstName"
            onChange={this.updateProfile.bind(this)}
            defaultValue={profile.firstName} />
          <br />
          <input
            id="lastName"
            onChange={this.updateProfile.bind(this)}
            defaultValue={profile.lastName} />
          <br />
          <input
            id="city"
            onChange={this.updateProfile.bind(this)}
            defaultValue={profile.city} />
          <br />
          <input
            id="email"
            onChange={this.updateProfile.bind(this)}
            defaultValue={profile.email} />
          <br />
          <textarea
            id="bio"
            onChange={this.updateProfile.bind(this)}
            defaultValue={profile.bio} />
          <br />
          <button onClick={this.submitUpdate.bind(this)}>Done</button>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      content = (
        <div>
          <h4>Name: </h4>
          <span>{profile.firstName}</span>
          <span>{profile.lastName}</span><br/>
          <h4>City: </h4>
          <span>{profile.city}</span><br/>
          <h4>Bio :</h4>
          <p>{profile.bio}</p><br />
          <button onClick={this.toggleEdit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AccountEditor
```

Answer (score 7):

You should replace `defaultValue` with `value = { this.state.someProp }`. So an example with your code would be

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isEditing: false,
      profile: props.profile // Setting up the initial data from the passed prop
    }
  }
```

and

```
<input id="firstName"
       onChange={ this.updateProfile.bind(this) }
       value={ this.state.profile.firstName } />
```

More about using react with form elements in [these docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Thanks! That **almost** worked but pointed me in the right direction. Setting the state where you suggested crashed the component so I moved the logic to componentDidMount() and it worked.

Comment: @crashspringfield the component crashed, because I missed `props` from `super`. You need to add your `props` to the function `super` as follows `super(props)` and it should work as expected. No need to add `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Also, defaultValue={} was more of the behavior I was looking for. When I just used value={}, it wouldn't update the state with what I typed; it was always the value.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again.

Comment: @crashspringfield as for the updating the values - you need to check out the docs about controlled inputs. It is recommended to use `ref` to refer to input values  and then update values with `onChange` handler method.